# Large CSV Go channels too much memory

Tags: csv, go, blocking, channel

Ok so I have a massive 2.5G CSV file which is about 25million or so records with about 20 columns.. I am trying to use GO to process this monster and do some formatting then inserting into a database. I have this basic code setup with channels because I figured it would be the fastest using go routines and such: 
[here](https://play.golang.org/p/5_dgSK1dFgL)

The problem being is because it is blocking, my channel just gets STUFFED with an insane amount of data and before I know it my memory is out of control. So before any processing or inserting gets done it fails.

Could someone help me out with this code and see if I can simultaneously build up the queue from reading the file WHILE processing and inserting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every record of your big CSV file you start a new goroutine. Every goroutine allocates `~2kB` stack. It's not recommended to start a goroutine for everything.

Try to use a pipeline, the main goroutine would read the records and send trough a `channel1`.

You start eg. 10 worker goroutines that process the records received from `channel1` and send the processed values trough `channel2`.

Then some other 10 goroutines would receive the values from `channel2` and insert it to the database.

[Here](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) are some examples for pipelines.